# Video does not automatically play on beamer (Auto-play)

Tags: beamer, media9, video

I want to include a video in my beamer presentation and I would like that the latter starts automatically when the slide opens.

Everything is fine  until now (I can read the video on the pdf) except that I still need to click on the video to start it.

I am reading the pdf with AcrobatReader (last version) on macOS 10.13. (High Sierra).

This is the code that I'm using:

I thought that the "activate=pageopen" option would be sufficient but it seems not.

Thanks in advance for your help.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{media9}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[plain]
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
     \node[anchor=south west, inner sep=0pt] at (current page.south west) {%
       \includemedia[
         addresource=trump.mov,
         activate=pageopen,
         flashvars={source=trump.mov&autoPlay=true},
         width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight
       ]{}{VPlayer.swf}%
     };
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is a known issue with `VPlayer.swf`. Try `VPlayer9.swf` instead.

Comment: A new version, **0.89**, has just been uploaded to CTAN and should be available within ~2 days via package managers. It fixes the autoplay issue (tested with `random.mp4` contained in the package).

Comment: @AlexG Would you like to write a short answer that the issue is solved with the new version?

Comment: I will have to run some test first. I am not that sure.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue described is due to a bug that has been fixed in the meantime.